# How to manage code in odoo between interface and git

Tags: git, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10

where i'm working we are a team of odoo developers and we have an integrator who validates our developements , we use git to manage our developements , but there is a developer in our team that modifies and adds fields and models and views directly into the interface without passing by git , is that going to affect the management of our code ? is it bad to do it or just not preferable to do it?

i have a new task to do , they ask me to add some fields based on the fields that the developer added directly using the interface, i usually take the git files of our project and inherit to modify or add fields, but since he is modifying using the interface, how am i going to do that ?

thank you!

**in more simple words , if we already use a version source system like git to manage code is it acceptable to modify server code directly without passing by git ?**

Comment: So you're saying that all of your team except one uses git to version control changes? And now you have to modify changes he's made? Are you able to see his changes now? Sorry if that last one's a dumb question, I've never used odoo before.

Comment: @ElderFuthark yes the changes are visible on the odoo web interface, but since the modifications were done directly on the database using the odoo web interface, there is no files in git about these modifications

Comment: Maybe someone with Odoo experience can assist more. My two cents is that this developer who isn't using git, should start. With the rest of your team using git and one guy not, it will eventually affect the management of your code more severely. It already is, given your last question. I'm not sure if moving his stuff into git directly is possible. Maybe this plugin would help (https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/11.0/project_git/)? Again, I'm not sure; maybe see if someone else with more Odoo experience is more knowledgeable.

Comment: The dev should be making their changes via git rather than directly in the database as the changes won't be present in a fresh install.

Comment: @simeh when you talk about "using the interface" do you mean Odoo Studio?

Answer (score 0):

It is not preferred to add code directly from the web interface.
If in case you are having a meeting with the Client and need to show changes immediately then direct changes from the web interface can be helpful. It will save you time. Later you need to add the code on the module level.

Also, the code that is directly added from the web server will only be available for that particular database only. If you create any new database, then for that database also you need to add the code manually from the web interface. Now imagine repeating the same thing for 10-20 databases or even more.

My Opinion: You need to ask that developer to add code on module level and remove from the web interface otherwise you might face difficulties in future to add any functionality depending on that particular code.